# getting line of a literal?

Tags: java, antlr4

Is there any way of getting the line and position of a _LITERAL_NAMES?

For example :

```
constant returns [String typeS, int line, int pos]
     : sign number {$typeS = "integer"; $line = $number.line; $pos = $number.pos;}
     | 'true'      {$typeS = "boolean"; $line = ????; $pos = ????}
     | 'false'     {$typeS = "boolean"; $line = ????; $pos = ????}
     ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
constant returns [String typeS, int line, int pos]
 : sign number {$typeS = "integer"; $line = $number.line; $pos = $number.pos;}
 | t='true'    {$typeS = "boolean"; $line = $t.line; $pos = $t.pos;}
 | t='false'   {$typeS = "boolean"; $line = $t.line; $pos = $t.pos;}
 ;
```